# Django: why when I use Ghostscript via popen in django do I get a "file not found" error

Tags: python, django, ghostscript, subprocess

I am trying to use ghostscript to convert a pdf to jpg from inside Django, but when I try to use subprocess.popen to run a ghostscript command I get a "file not found" error. If I run exactly the same script from a py file via the command line it works correctly.

Here is my script:

```
import os
import subprocess

path =  "/tmp/e15hntd/"

### this next line is what seems to cause the file not found error

sp = subprocess.Popen("gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOUTPUTFILE=" + path + "/static.jpg " + path + "/source.pdf")
```

after searching around for possible solutions I tried several alternative versions of the offending line e.g.:

```
sp = subprocess.Popen(['gs', '-dSAFER', '-dNOPAUSE', '-dQUIET', '-dBATCH', '-sDEVICE=jpeg', '-sOUTPUTFILE=' + path + "/static.jpg", path + "/source.pdf"])
```

or:

```
sp = subprocess.call("gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOUTPUTFILE=" + path + "/static.jpg " + path + "/source.pdf")
```

Here is the full error:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory

Traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
366.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
196.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
209.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
1054.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, True)
File "/home/Django/Update/admin.py" in save_model
41.             sp = subprocess.call("gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOUTPUTFILE=" + unique_path + "/static.jpg " + unique_path + "/source.pdf" + unique_path + "/source.pdf")
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py" in call
480.     return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py" in __init__
633.                             errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py" in _execute_child
1139.                 raise child_exception
```

Comment: Surely you use `subprocess.Popen`, not `subprocess.pOpen`? Also, please include the full traceback of errors; there is *lots* of info in those to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting means that the `subprocess` module cannot find the executable it wants to run.

If the script runs from the command-line then the `gs` executable clearly exists, so it looks like the `gs` executable is not on the `PATH` that your Django application is  running with.  Does it help if you specify the full path to `gs` (e.g. `/usr/bin/gs`) instead?

Incidentally, I get the same error message if I try to get `subprocess` to start a nonexistent executable:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call("nonexistent")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**EDIT**: if your process uses command-line arguments, the executable name and the argument must be specified as separate list items, as in the second of your attempts at running `gs`:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call("ls /usr")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>>> subprocess.call(["ls", "/usr"])
bin  games  include  lib  lib32  lib64  local  sbin  share  src  X11R6
0
```

The first example didn't work because I don't have an executable named `ls /usr` anywhere on my system.

Could you try modifying the second of your attempts to use the full path of `gs`, for example:

```
sp = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/gs', '-dSAFER', '-dNOPAUSE', '-dQUIET', '-dBATCH', '-sDEVICE=jpeg', '-sOUTPUTFILE=' + path + "/static.jpg", path + "/source.pdf"])
```

Comment: I tried using the full path "/usr/bin/gs" but I still get the same error.

Comment: I have now also tried using imagemagick but I get the same subprocess related error as before.